Save the output of the MERGE statement to a table that is not a variable
I have these two tables:
CREATE DATABASE MergeDemo
GO
    
USE MergeDemo
GO
    
CREATE TABLE SourceProducts(
    ProductID       INT,
    ProductName     VARCHAR(50),
    Price           DECIMAL(9,2)
)
GO
    
INSERT INTO SourceProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(1,'Table',100)
INSERT INTO SourceProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(2,'Desk',80)
INSERT INTO SourceProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(3,'Chair',50)
INSERT INTO SourceProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(4,'Computer',300)
GO
    
CREATE TABLE TargetProducts(
    ProductID       INT,
    ProductName     VARCHAR(50),
    Price           DECIMAL(9,2)
)
GO
    
INSERT INTO TargetProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(1,'Table',100)
INSERT INTO TargetProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(2,'Desk',180)
INSERT INTO TargetProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(5,'Bed',50)
INSERT INTO TargetProducts(ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES(6,'Cupboard',300)
GO

Now I want to run a MERGE statement and output the results:
USE MergeDemo;

MERGE TargetProducts AS Target
USING SourceProducts AS Source
ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        Target.ProductName = Source.ProductName,
        Target.Price = Source.Price
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, Price)
    VALUES (Source.ProductID, Source.ProductName, Source.Price)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
    DELETE
OUTPUT $action,
    DELETED.ProductID,
    DELETED.ProductName,
    DELETED.Price,
    INSERTED.ProductID,
    INSERTED.ProductName,
    INSERTED.Price;

And the results are:

You can see that this table has repeated columns. Is there a way I can write these results to a table I define? I have seen examples where the table is created as a variable, but that does not give me the flexibility I want.

Have you tried to use OUTPUT ... INTO with an actual table? The OUTPUT clause documentation examples show several variations. The last example even uses the OUTPUT of MERGE to insert into another table, as part of a more complex query

Why do you want this anyway? For auditing? Preserving changed data? Other features may be a better option, eg temporal tables or change tracking. Why do you mention that this table has repeated columns ?

The last example (K) in the link above, when implemented, returns: A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

The docs aren't wrong, provided you use the actual version they target. Which means you're probably using an old database version. Which version are you using ? And did you try OUTPUT INTO an actual table?

By the way, that example relies on using one table for deletion. What if you wanted to store all DELETES, UPDATES, INSERTS in the same log table?

The very first example in the MERGE (Transact-SQL) documentation shows how to do this. It implicitly spreads the deleted.* and inserted.* columns across the output table but there's no reason you cannot be explicit to define the output columns in any particular order you need... even interleaving the inserted and deleted columns as pairs if you so desire.

@FaCoffee in that case you're using the wrong tool for the job. MERGE isn't an audit tool. Triggers are.  Temporal tables or the built-in Audit are even better. Change tracking can retrieve the IDs of all modified rows, even deleted ones. All of them work without requiring modifications to the actual operation (INSERT, UPDATE etc)

@FaCoffee in this particular case, given that WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN     DELETE, you're essentially replacing one table with another. You can do that instantaneously by using partition switching between the staging table and the target, eg ALTER TABLE Source SWITCH TO Target

@FaCoffee there's also the heavier Change Data Capture mechanism, which is heavier only in the sense that it stores entire rows in a separate table. Whatever the real business requirement is, it's probably already covered by suitable, optimized SQL Server features
